# Using ubuntustudio-installer to install low-latency audio packages on 20.04, getting error E: Unable to fetch some archives

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, ubuntu-studio

Trying to install packages for low latency audio with JACK on Ubuntu 20.04.4, following the guide linked on the [Ubuntu Studio Installer page](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/) ([this one](https://frontpagelinux.com/tutorials/easily-install-jack-audio-with-ubuntu-studio-installer/)).
I tried the following:

1. Ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y` and rebooted.
2. Installed `sudo apt install ubuntustudio-installer` on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
3. Enabled Backports PPA
4. Selected packages: linux-lowlatency, ubuntustudio-lowlatency-settings,ubuntustudio-performance-tweaks, ubuntustudio-audio
5. Installer gets to 89% and then throws error "E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?"
6. Tried the usual things to address this problem: `apt update`, `apt update --fix-missing`, `apt clean` followed by `update`. Even `apt upgrade` and `apt upgrade -f`. Likely others I have forgotten---been at this a couple days. Happy to run through everything again from the start though.

Stymied now. Any advice? Happy to provide any logs thought relevant, but I'm not sure at this stage what would be helpful.

Edit: Thanks to @David, I have narrowed the problem to the ubuntustudio-audio package---installing the other packages individually gave me no trouble. Attempting to install this package produces the above error.

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the packages one at a time? I would also lose the minus y so you can see all the details.

Comment: Good shout @David, many thanks. I did try this, but started with ubuntustudio-audio, which made no difference so gave up instantly. I tried again just then and I was able to successfully install linux-lowlatency, ubuntustudio-lowlatency-settings, and ubuntustudio-performance-tweaks.

The problem appears to be restricted to ubuntustudio-audio.

Otherwise, no change---89% complete then throws the error.

Comment: So now you know where to focus.

Comment: Regarding dropping the -y @David, I have no trouble seeing what the command is doing---it performs as expected. Just checks my ppas for package updates and since I've done this 1000 times by now, finds nothing and finishes.

The problem, I think is with the ubuntustudio-installer command, which launches a GUI, and hides any output from the terminal. I can't figure out a way to make it more verbose.

Comment: Yes @David---very helpful! Thanks :) And I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @David for unblocking my train of thought (see comments on question).

The problem appears to have been some kind of repo conflict.

This error was obscured by the ubuntustudio-audio GUI (which only provides the final line of the error message), but installing the package at the command line gives you the verbose error message:

```sh
Err:1 https://kx.studio/repo gcc5/free amd64 ardour amd64 2:5.12.0-1kxstudio2v5                                                                                 
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.199.108.133 443]                                                                                                                   
...
```

I don't quite understand, but it looks like it was trying to retrieve ardour from the wrong repo---kxstudio-repos.

Purged the kxstudio-repos package, and the installation proceeded cleanly.